# jquery .each() not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

im trying to hide a series of elements with the .each function replacing a for loop which wasn't working in IE9, while the code works in FF it wont work in IE.

```
var myArray=document.getElementsByName("hide[]");
$.each(myArray, function(i, id) {$("#" + myArray[i].attributes["id"].value).hide();});
```

not entirely sure whats failing

in for loop form

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
  {
  $("#" + myArray[i].attributes["id"].value).hide();
  }
```

Comment: _a for loop which wasn't working in IE9_ Can we see your `for` loop?

Comment: Why do you use this ugly mix of DOM and jQuery?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `$(myArray).hide()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you using `getElementsByName`?  Just use jQuery to get the elements, then just `.hide` them.

```
$('[name="hide[]"]').hide();
```

Comment: this does the trick so im upvoting before i can accept, question know a way to say have jquery single out one of an element in an array since while this gets the job done its a bit sloppy

Comment: Yes, `.eq(n)` will select the element at index `n`

Comment: The beauty and simplicity of jQuery , couldn't resist to upvote!